# How can I execute a code/function when a Grease Pencil layer is renamed?

Tags: grease-pencil, layers

I'm making a grease pencil addon, and to mantain my system integrity, **I need to check when a grease pencil layer has been renamed.**
(As far as I know, their name act basically as an ID).

I need to know when a renaming happens so I can trigger all the changes I need.

I learned about [Application Handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#module-bpy.app.handlers), and about [msgbus](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html) from an user here. But I'm not sure if they work for my needs. I wasn't able to make it work.

Any idea? (Thank you so much for the help)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Msgbus worked nice, I just had to:

```
owner = object()
subscribe_to_layer_info_change = bpy.types.GPencilLayer, "info"
...
bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=subscribe_to_layer_info_change,
    owner=owner,
    args=(),
    notify=msgbus_callback_on_layer_renamed,
    options={"PERSISTENT"},
    )
```